# CesiumJS web site wont work on mobile phones

Tags: cesiumjs

I created web application using CesiumJS.

On computers its working just fine, but on mobile just Reloading (Safari) and Error (Chrome).

I get Mac from my friend I use developer tools and see error on mobile (see picture)
[image]

I tried some solutions for this, to disable iFrame sandbox attribute, but wont works again.

The web site is:

[This is my web site](http://osgl.grf.bg.ac.rs/srbcorine)

Can you give me a solution please?

Thanks

Comment: To address the critical script-blocking problem it looks like you'll need to add `allow-scripts` to the properties in your iframe's sandbox attribute, which according to your website link is currently: `sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-forms"`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox.

Comment: I done that, but same thing. (But now I don't have Mac to see what is error, same or something new).

Comment: @fridge_light Notify

Comment: Have you updated the website? I'm still seeing the same sandbox properties for the iframe.

Comment: @fridge_light I cant update site, because I don't have request to access server.
I tried to change iFrame on localhost (I connected mobile on localhost) and add all possible items, the browser stay on page little more, but still the same.
I tried like i said in previous comment, to remove bootstrap and it works.
How to enable bootstrap :/

Comment: You could try loading the Bootstrap (and jQuery) scripts in the head rather than the body. As you can't update the website I can't test it, but my guess is that maybe Bootstrap is triggering the issue by modifying the iframe after the page has been loaded.

Comment: I tried that to set bootstrap.js and .css in head before cesium.js and Widget.css and still the same :/.

Answer (score 0):

I spent 30 hours working on different version of my Web site.
I tried without *bootstrap*, with *bootstrap*, with *scripts*, *allow-scripts*, everything.

I found a solution!!!!!!!!!

I put all my  and  tags in  tag in my *.html* document.
Also I used  tags from *Hello world.html* document.

My header looks like this now:

```
  <head>
    <!-- Use correct character set. -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Tell IE to use the latest, best version. -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Make the application on mobile take up the full browser screen and disable user scaling. -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Molim te radi</title>
    <!-- LBOOT -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">


      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="Cesium.js"></script>   
      <script src="CesiumBootstrap.js"></script>
      <script src="knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="Widgets/widgets.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="CesiumBootstrap.css" type="text/css">


  </head>
```

Just this  tags is all you (I) need!